# Iframe scroll bars issue

Tags: .net, html

On iframe if I leave out scrolling attribute still both scroll bars come ( disabled) when not required. If I set scrolling to auto  behavior is same. If I set scrolling to no then only those disabled scroll bars go away but I don't want that. I need to show them whenever they are required and other times if it's not required the grayed out scroll bars shouln't show up.

Comment: FF5 Win7 hides iFrame scrollbars when they're not in use. I just tested on jsfiddle.net, which uses the iframe code: `<iframe frameborder="0" class="js" style="border: 0pt none; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;" src="javascript:;"></iframe>`, so no special attributes or styles at work.